# Splitting a string with repeated characters into a list

Tags: python, regex, string

I am not well experienced with Regex but I have been reading a lot about it. Assume there's a string `s = '111234'` I want a list with the string split into `L = ['111', '2', '3', '4']`. My approach was to make a group checking if it's a digit or not and then check for a repetition of the group. Something like this

```
L = re.findall('\d[\1+]', s)
```

I think that `\d[\1+]` will basically check for either "digit" or "digit +" the same repetitions. I think this might do what I want.

Comment: Do you know if the string will contain only numbers?

Comment: @thefourtheye : No assume that it will contain non-digits as well

Comment: I have impression that you were looking for `r_e = "(1*)(2*)(3*)(4*)"` that gives `re.findall(r_e, s)[0]` => `('111', '2', '3', '4')`.

Comment: Through list is ordered collection: If you don't need order then you can use `r_e = "((?P<o>1+)|(?P<to>2+)|(?P<th>3+)|(?P<f>4+))*"` then `re.search(r_e, s).group('o', 'to', 'th', 'f')`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
>>> s='111234'
>>> [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"(\d)\1*", s)]
['111', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to group all the repeated characters, then you can also use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like this

```
from itertools import groupby
print ["".join(grp) for num, grp in groupby('111234')]
# ['111', '2', '3', '4']
```

If you want to make sure that you want only digits, then

```
print ["".join(grp) for num, grp in groupby('111aaa234') if num.isdigit()]
# ['111', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

```
s = '111234'

l = re.findall(r'((.)\2*)', s)
## it this stage i have [('111', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4')] in l

## now I am keeping only the first value from the tuple of each list
lst = [x[0] for x in l]

print lst
```

output:

```
['111', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: why was a tuple created? Was it because there were two groups to be found?

Comment: Yes, its for the two groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any libraries then here's the code:

```
s = "AACBCAAB"
L = []
temp = s[0]
for i in range(1,len(s)):
    if s[i] == s[i-1]:
        temp += s[i]
    else:
        L.append(temp)
        temp = s[i]
    if i == len(s)-1:
        L.append(temp)
print(L)
```

Output:

```
['AA', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'AA', 'B']
```