# Python group repeating characters in list together

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to split a string of 1s and 0s into a list of repeated groups of these characters.

Example:

`m = '00001100011111000'`

Goes to:

`m = ['0000', '11', '000', '11111', '000']`

How would I do this in efficient concise code? Would regex work for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group i consecutive identical character in a string into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691784/group-i-consecutive-identical-character-in-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: Better duplicate: [Splitting a string with repeated characters into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882922/splitting-a-string-with-repeated-characters-into-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `re`. For example:

```py
import re

m = "00001100011111000"

print(["".join(v) for v, _ in re.findall(r"((.)\2*)", m)])
```

Prints:

```
['0000', '11', '000', '11111', '000']
```

---

Other regex:

```py
print(re.findall(r"0+|1+", m))
```

Prints:

```
['0000', '11', '000', '11111', '000']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use itertools groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
m = '00001100011111000'
["".join(g) for _, g in groupby(m)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

["".join(g) for k, g in groupby(m)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
m = "00001100011111000"
[s.group(0) for s in re.finditer(r"(\d)\1*", m)]
```

Output:

```
['0000', '11', '000', '11111', '000']
```